# Calling helper functions without calling the static class they live in

Tags: c#

I am making a DLL of helper functions and I want to call them without calling the class they live in. For example:

```
namespace HelperFunctions
{
    public static class Greetings
    {
        public static void greet()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("hello!");
        }
    }
```

How to I modify the above code so that I can do this:

```
using HelperFunctions;

namespace MyConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            greet();
        }
    }
}
```

Assumptions/Understandings:

- I understand I can call `Greetings.greet()` but I dont want to.
- I understand I will have to come up with unique names for my functions that won't clash with anything from the System namespace (or whatever other references I am using)

Comment: This is coming in the next version of C#.

Comment: I believe VB has this feature; C# does not [yet]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presently, you can't.

When the next version of C# is released, you'll be able to write:

```
using HelperFunctions.Greetings;
```

and it will work.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn683793.aspx -- see section on Static Using Statements